Performance Problem In SQL when using Function for some Enums
I have a table with some states. Some of the states means ongoing state, since another programmers may use queries for getting them,
like "All On going orders" etc.
I created a function like this because maybe ongoing orders states change later:
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetStates]()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT CAST('registered' AS VARCHAR(75)) AS OrderState
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'OnBoardModify' OrderState
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'OnCanceling' OrderState
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'OnSending' OrderState

When I use this function it is slower than the old queries.
Old queries
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Order 
WHERE state IN ('OnBoardModify','registered','OnCanceling')

New query
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Order_MOT  
WHERE OMSOrderState IN (
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fn_GetOpenOrderState]()
)

Is there any better way for this?
When I use table or functions or...
plan link 


Why not create a states table instead?

it isnt even slower?

But your two calls aren't even equivalent? You have 3 in the IN and 4 in  your function

using function is slower because for each row in Order_MOT, the function is called and executed . which is the expected behaviour. and that's why it's not a proper use case there. also what's wrong with the first query it's a reasonable solution for your problem. more robust solution if you have several values to compare with , as jarlh mentioned, is to put them in a table and join with it

@siggemannen  They are in real Tests. i just didnt copy all part of codes cause idk i can use real names or no

@eshirvana Ty for Tips but the table is a way slower...
|

@eshirvana  I edided question, and added their plans

@javadrabbani remove screenshots and put them in pasteplan and provide the links. for the table you probably need proper indexes on state column

@eshirvana Ty i didnt know about this ,

Your queries don't work anyway (as intended). Qualify all columns!

@jarlh i updated question with a real plan

@javadrabbani, that's what I read.

BTW, when comparing queries, make sure to run each query twice. Data on disk only is much slower.

hmm u right , let me try them in another way, but the plans are not good,
1 is index seek and anothers are table scans,,,

Start with correcting them before comparing performance.

@javadrabbani 2nd query if you change it to a join, you would get index seek SELECT o.* FROM dbo.Order_MOT o join OnGoingOrderStates c on c.OMSOrderState=o.OMSOrderState

This sounds like an extremely brittle process you are creating. If I understand what you are doing is using sql to mimic the values from an enum in your code. This is very risky and brittle as all get out. If your enum changes by adding or removing a value you have to also remember to update your sql. This is highly likely to cause issues. You really should be using lookup tables here instead of storing the text value over and over. Consider how awful this will be if you change the text. You have a denormalized architecture here which is nothing short of painful to work with.

yes you are right @eshirvana Thanks

@SeanLange
it is true what u say but in our company , speed is most important things...
we dont have even relation between tables cause our cto thinks it goind to slow inserts...

Using a function (scalar or table valued) in a SQL query breaks the set approach to data processing that can use parallelism and index search and requires a sequential execution of the function for each row of the table (RBAR).
Since version 2017, improvements to the optimizer (Intelligent Query Processing) and more particularly within the framework of the FROID project (scalar UDF : inligning), allow the SQL of a function to be reincorporated as a set expression whenever possible.
If your instance is in 2019 or higher, you can benefit from this by redesigning the UDF as a scalar one, rewrite the query to use the scalar function and checking that your database is in backward compatibility mode 2019 or 2022 depending on your instance.
Otherwise, remove this function and restore the original code in your query.
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetStates](@state  VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
RETURN CASE WHEN @state IN ('registered', 'OnBoardModify', 'OnCanceling', 'OnSending') 
              THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
       END
END;

SELECT *
FROM   dbo.Order 
WHERE  [dbo].[fn_GetStates](state) = 1;


thanks for Info , ye it is 2019 and  I will try this
